# database auto generate primary key

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, java-ee-7

I have two entities parent with an id generate from database by using 
  @Column(insertable=false,columnDefinition="integer not null default (nextval'seq'::regclass)")
    @Id long id;
for some reason I want database engine create this id my problem if this parent have children how they know and set parent_id foreign key

Comment: If you need to use a database sequence, you don't need to provide a `columnDefinition`, simply use `@Generated(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "regclassGenerator")`, where `regclassGenerator` is a `@SequenceGenerator`. That being said, Eclipselink should be able to handle this situation, what is the exact problem you're experiencing?

Comment: If you don't use the Sequence annotation, JPA doesn't know how to get the value or handle it to use anywhere else.  See https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/PrimaryKey